# Horizontal alignment of widgets in ipython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Consider the following example:

```py
%pylab inline

from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.html.widgets import interact

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(values):
    data = {
        'foo': ([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9]),
        'bar': ([1, 2, 3], [9, 4, 1]),
        'baz': ([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2])
    }    

    for item in values:
        plt.plot(*data[item])


__ = interact(f, values=widgets.SelectMultiple(
    height=1000,  # it is going to be a long list
    description=' ',
    options=['foo', 'bar', 'baz']))
```

Having this I got a SelectMultiple widget and inline plot below it. As you can see the SelectMultiple list may be very long, so obvious intention is to   place it with plot into HBox. However pyplot is not a Notebook widget.

Are there any ways to solve the problem without tricky workarounds?

Thank you.